# Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown> on SetContentView

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, exception

I am developing a C# android app, which contains 3 activities and 3 layouts. the main activity consist of 3 buttons each one pass the user into a specific app. The first button takes to the `FirstAct` and it contains some textViews and a button which retake the user to the `MainActivity`. Now after the return button is clicked, and I re-click the first button in the `MainActivity`, this exception is being thrown.

**FirstAct.cs**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FirstLay);
        reBtn.Click += delegate
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        };
    }
    catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
 }
```

**FirstLay**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:max="8"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
<TextView
    android:text="ما هو جنسك ؟"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
    android:textSize="22dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:text="ذكر"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dip" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="أنثى"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:textSize="20dip" />
</RadioGroup>
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:maxLength="3"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:text="يومياً"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ليس كل يوم"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RadioGroup>
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="نعم"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="لا"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RadioGroup>
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup4"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="نعم"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="لا"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RadioGroup>
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup5"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="نعم"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="لا"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton10"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RadioGroup>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="ادخل طولك (بالسنتيمتر):"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/height"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:maxLength="3" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:text="ادخل وزنك (بالكيلوغرام):"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:id="@+id/weight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:maxLength="3" />
<TextView
    android:text="النتيجة: "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/BMI"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/waist"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:maxLength="3" />
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton11"
        android:text="نعم، مباشرون"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="16dip" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="نعم، غير مباشرون"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton12"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="16dip" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="لا"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton13"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="15dip" />
</RadioGroup>
<TextView
    android:text="جاري حساب النتيجة.."
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<TextView
    android:layout_height="430dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="مجموع النقاط (score):"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/res"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="70dp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:background="@drawable/btn"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="العودة"
    android:textSize="22dip"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="111dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1/9"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:background="@drawable/arr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:background="@drawable/ll"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView3"
        android:visibility="gone" />
 </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
05-31 22:50:16.619 I/art     (11433): Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1086(84KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(68KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 
 242MB/256MB, paused 240us total 5.171ms
05-31 22:50:16.619 I/art     (11433): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-31 22:50:16.629 I/art     (11433): Clamp target GC heap from 258MB to 256MB
05-31 22:50:16.629 I/art     (11433): Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 147(6KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 
 242MB/256MB, paused 268us total 8.105ms
05-31 22:50:16.629 I/art     (11433): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-31 22:50:16.639 I/art     (11433): Clamp target GC heap from 258MB to 256MB
05-31 22:50:16.639 I/art     (11433): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 73(14KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 
  242MB/256MB, paused 277us total 9.346ms
05-31 22:50:16.639 I/art     (11433): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 16MB allocation
05-31 22:50:16.639 I/art     (11433): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-31 22:50:16.649 I/art     (11433): Clamp target GC heap from 258MB to 256MB
05-31 22:50:16.649 I/art     (11433): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 242MB/256MB, paused 264us total 8.461ms
05-31 22:50:16.649 W/art     (11433): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 16777228 byte allocation with 14484880 free bytes and 13MB until OOM"
05-31 22:50:16.649 I/art     (11433): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-31 22:50:16.649 I/art     (11433): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-31 22:50:16.654 I/art     (11433): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-31 22:50:16.659 I/art     (11433): Clamp target GC heap from 258MB to 256MB
05-31 22:50:16.659 I/art     (11433): Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 242MB/256MB, paused 238us total 6.470ms
05-31 22:50:16.659 I/art     (11433): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-31 22:50:16.669 I/art     (11433): Clamp target GC heap from 258MB to 256MB
05-31 22:50:16.669 I/art     (11433): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 242MB/256MB, paused 274us total 8.247ms
05-31 22:50:16.669 I/art     (11433): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 16MB allocation
05-31 22:50:16.669 I/art     (11433): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-31 22:50:16.674 I/art     (11433): Clamp target GC heap from 258MB to 256MB
05-31 22:50:16.674 I/art     (11433): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 242MB/256MB, paused 243us total 8.064ms
05-31 22:50:16.674 W/art     (11433): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 16777228 byte allocation with 14484880 free bytes and 13MB until OOM"
05-31 22:50:16.679 D/skia    (11433): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>`
```

The strange thing is that when I click the button for the first time in the `Mainactivity`, the first activity is launched without problem only in the second time it throws the exception. I first thought that maybe the background image I have is causing this so I removed it but that's didn't worked. Then I have put `NoHistory = true` but also didn't worked. Also I have tried to finish the activity before starting the `MainActivity` on the return button click. So I don't know what is causing the problem, would you please help me to find out ?

Comment: If you get an exception, please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I have added the output, it is throwing OOM Exception

Comment: Looks like the memory of your phone is full, have you tried freeing it up?

Comment: I would start of removing all the background drawables to figure out which one is causing issues. Also make sure that you scale your bitmaps and put them in the appropriate folders. Otherwise you will encounter these OOM Exceptions. Not sure if that OOM causes the InflationException too. But if there is more to the InflationException, then post that too.

Comment: @Cheesebaron There was a `PNG` image 5.6 KB, dimensions: 310 * 427 I have removed it and it worked properly with no exception. But this image is necessary so what can I do to keep it without throwing this exception ?